# sparkSQL interaction with hive metastore

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

> I try to figure out how and where the execution happens with sparkSQL
> query Hive Metastore.

**SparkSQl run's on the "spark" engine as we already know but how does interact with hive metastore in these scenarios (internal and external tables):**

- SparkSQl uses "spark" distributed SQL engine but hive uses "map-reduce or tez" engine, does spark copy data into memory and run query or does use thrift server to just interact with Hive metastore ? reference [Distributed SQL engine](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-distributed-sql-engine.html), I try to understand where does happens computation and if can be optimized in a way to reduce execution time.
  I do know result is a dataframe so that is an overhead so understanding this execution and best practices maybe would have better idea where I can change execution behaviour.
- SparkSQl uses "spark" distributed SQL engine but hive uses "spark" distributed engine, does spark use thrift server to interact with Hive metastore, does happens any copy and where does execution of the query happens?

**Note:** All this questions is due the fact that direct hive query using beeline or hue is fast but in SparkSQL is very slow. I do know inferring schema and copy results from query converting into a dataframe takes place but where all this execution happens and how to avoid bottlenecks, hope not to get answer to just read directly parquet files into spark and go from there, my main point is interacting with HIVE metastore (internal and external tables).

On top of all: converting HIVEQL queries to Pyspark directly does improve performance but my question is not related to this approach ...

Comment: The question is very vague and "optimize to increase execution time"... seems odd

Comment: I do think is on point, that were a simple mistake and not odd from my end (should be increase performance or decrease execution time for the query). Is all about where does happen execution when query is submitted from sparkSQL … different engines and how does work spark SQL distributed engine here, does copy data, does copy results or how in general works

Comment: because official doc is not clear on this part how does handle this tasks and not sure if data needs to be already in spark mem to take advantage of optimization (all is mostly listed is that hiveQL queries are supported natively and with shark project (first sparksql name) were meant to replace hive but is not the case anymore, is just interaction between spark and hive metastore …

Comment: Believe me too vague.

Comment: I don’t think so, is on point on how sparkSQL uses hive metastore … were computation takes place (what engine), I do not see anything “vague” here.

Comment: What is slow? Too many partitions?

Comment: Exactly, hive is partitioned and results back to spark need to be “manually” adjusted to make it efficient, this is the reason for asking on how sparkSQL does work with hive metastore so can know how to optimize, I do suspect based on what I see is that query is sent to hive mr and brings back the results and repartitions with defaults … but at this point for me is just speculative so understanding this interaction can plan on how to use hive efficiently, shark project (prior becoming sparkSQL) purpose were meant to solve hive limitations and run compatible hiveQL queries …

Comment: … but seems for me is like interacting with “external” hive instance and just getting results back to spark, so not sure where does SQL distributed engine plays a role here if Hive engine is different than spark (mr, tez).

Comment: Obwrly partititioned tables cause issues in the HM from experience. External or nit is not an issue. Te not relevant

Comment: And this is the core for me to understand from this question because is just to expensive to read entire tables and repartition, this behavior I do address to just migrate hiveQL to pyspark&sparkSQL but would rather find an easier approach to just migration … what then is the role in of sql distribution engine in this part and why deviated sparkSQL so much from initial shark purpose then ?

Comment: I can’t help you.